# Detect malicious content in an base64 string of Image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, validation, base64

I have an upload feature for Image Files. 
I have added restrictions on file type but there is also one scenario where someone could add code in Image String and upload it. 
How can I detect these type of files which look normal but their content could be harmful?

Comment: What are you going to do with this string? Why can it be harmful? You should send binary data (i.e the Blob directly, not its 34% bigger b64 string representation), store it as binary and never have anything trying to execute it.

Comment: This string is used for further processing on image and also to populate the Image Elements. By Harmful I mean it contains a script at the end of the string. I am no security expert but I know hackers try these types of methods. So binary format discards everything extra or what's the benefit?

Comment: binary data ensures that only the image parser will ever read it, it avoids posting and storing and serving a 34% bigger data and it's easier for the browser to cache at getting.